# How do I parse an RSS feed for display without creating nodes, etc

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

New to Drupal and want to do the following:  Display a list of the publications of a particular author from an RSS feed on a page for each author. I have a Wordpress site where I do this (Simple Pie Rss Reader) but cannot find exactly what I am looking for in Drupal.

The feeds module is powerful and useful for importing entries of an RSS feed as nodes, but this is much more than I need -- I do not what to create new nodes, etc.  All I want to do is display a list of data from the feed.

Each author has his or her own feed.  I would like the list of publications from the feed be in a field of the author content type.  Could someone point me toward an appropriate Drupal module or provide some beginner advice as to what the best-practices for implementing this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the custom formatters module to accomplish this -- just a little php code to display the RSS feed that is entered as a field in the user's profile.

Link: http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create conditional RSS Feeds using the Views module.
http://drupal.org/project/views

To a begineer with this module it may be difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks as though Views was the piece I was missing.  I can create a view formatted the way I want with the feed imported through the D7 core Aggregator -- the only piece I am missing is a way to have the view I created be a field for a node.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the Views Field View to to embed a view as a field in a view. https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view